# How to get the index

Tags: c#, arrays, picturebox, indexof

For a school project, I have to make a table reservation system,
I made the following (just a small part).

```
PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[70] { pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3,etc..  };
foreach (PictureBox p in pb)
{
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    p.BackColor = Color.White;
    p.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(mouseOn);
    p.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(mouseClick);
}

private void mouseOn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((PictureBox)sender).BackColor = Color.Green;
}

private void mouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reservationForm rf = new reservationForm();
    rf.ShowDialog();
}
```

I chose for pictureboxes to represent the tables, the default `BackColor` is white, and when the mouse enters the `BackColor` turns green.

When you click on 1 of those `PictureBox`es my `reservationForm` will open, this is where you can further fill in the details to book the table.

but the part where I get stuck now is that I don't know on my reservation form which `PictureBox` I clicked, so I need to get something like the index of the `PictureBox` array.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know how to do it! :)

You're already doing it correctly on the `mouseOn` event handler. Just do the same cast of the `sender` parameter.

```
private void mouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox clickedBox = (PictureBox)sender;

    reservationForm rf = new reservationForm();
    rf.ShowDialog();
}
```

If you need the index, you can use `Array.IndexOf`, assuming your `pb` array is a class level variable and not a method local.

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(pb, clickedBox);
```

Comment: but now i want to get the index from the array of the picturebox array, i cant seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check sender

```
private void mouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PicterBox pb = (PicterBox)sender;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "MouseOn" you already use `(PictureBox)sender` to get *a reference to* the picturebox.
Then you can walk through the array to compare the picturebox at a specific index to the clicked one. When you have a match, you found the index.

```
var clicked = (PictureBox)sender;
int index = 0;
while (index < pb.Length && pb[index] != clicked) index = index+1;
// now index is either 70 (if not found) or the position you want (0..69)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set in for cycle a name at each picturebox equals at the corrispondent index. So in the listener u can use

> PicterBox pb = (PicterBox)sender;

and get the name that is the index.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. I will suggest some of them:

- Create a public class variable or property and store the current selected Picturebox on the click event, so you can access it from the form;
- Pass in the Picturebox for the constructor of the form (creating a constructor that accepts this info and stores it in an internal variable).